# Compute a stationary distribution for this chain. Is it unique? Compute $m_{i}=E_{i}(\tau_{i}(1))$ for each $i\in S$. Assume $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expected-value

Classify the states for the Markov chain with matrix
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0\\
0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.8\\
0.25 & 0 & 0.75 & 0\\
0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.4
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Compute a stationary distribution for this chain. Is it unique? Compute $m_{i}=E_{i}\left(\tau_{i}(1)\right)$ for each $i\in S$. Assume $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

This is what I get until now but I am having problems with the uniqueness and computing $m_{i}=E_{i}\left(\tau_{i}(1)\right)$.

\begin{align*}
x_{1}&=0.5x_{1}+ 0x_{2} + 0.25x_{3}+0x_{4}\\
x_{2}&=0x_{1}+ 0.2x_{2} + 0x_{3}+0.6x_{4}\\ 
x_{3}&=0.5x_{1}+ 0x_{2} + 0.75x_{3}+0x_{4}\\
x_{4}&=0x_{1}+ 0.8x_{2} + 0x_{3}+0.4x_{4}\\
1&=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \frac{1}{3}-\frac{7}{12}x_4\\
x_2 &= \frac{3}{4}x_4\\
x_3 &= \frac{2}{3}-\frac{7}{6}x_4\\
x_4 &= x_4
\end{align*}

Stationary distribution

$$x = \left[\frac{1}{3}-\frac{7}{12}x_4,\frac{3}{4}x_4, \frac{2}{3} - \frac{7}{6}x_4, x_4\right].$$

Comment: You need to place some restrictions on $x_4$ in order for $x$ to be a valid stochastic vector. For example, with $x_4=1$, two of the components are negative.

Comment: There are obviously two noncommunicating sets of states. Each of these subchains might have its own stationary distribution, and if so, then every convex combination of them is a stationary distribution of the entire chain.